# Programatically navigate page with query params ionic 4

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, ionic4

I want to pass data to another page.
My app-routing.module is like this :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'web-page/:url', loadChildren: './web-page/web-page.module#WebPagePageModule' },
  { path: 'qrscan', loadChildren: './qrscan/qrscan.module#QrscanPageModule' },

];
```

With HTML i can successfully pass data :

```
   <ion-button expand="full" [routerLink]="['/web-page/', urlBooking]" routerDirection="forward">BOOKING</ion-button>
```

But i am struggling to do in typescript :

```
this.router.navigate(['web-page'], { queryParams: { 'url': "https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180387/xcode-failed-to-download-use-the-purchases-page-to-try-again" } });
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont say anything about what's not working, but you might want to url encode your query param. This should work just fine. And use `decodeURIComponent` where you use that param.

```
const url = encodeURIComponent("https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180387/xcode-failed-to-download-use-the-purchases-page-to-try-again");
this.router.navigate(['web-page'], { queryParams: { url } });
```